# Is it possible to determine a value for a key in an array using conditions?

Tags: php

Can I set a value for an array key using a condition? In the following example I am using ternary operator, not sure how to do that with an if-else statement

```
function conditional_array($value)
{
    $array = [ 'key' => $value == 'foo' ? 'bar' : 'boo' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Pass the array you want to run this function as an argument of your function and you function can look something like this:

```
function conditional_array($array, $value_check)
{
    // Loop over array keys and values and set the key using the result of your ternary expression.
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = $key === $value_check ? ' bar' : 'boo';
    }
    return($array);
}

// Example of an array.
$array = ['foo' => 'x', 'different' => 'y', ];

// Invoke you function and store the result in a new variable. 
$result = conditional_array($array, 'foo');
```

Here's an [interactive example](https://3v4l.org/vl2l5) as well.